# Equals returns false between classes - proxy and bean

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have this annotation above method, that is on a bean, which is proxied by Spring (BeanNameAutoProxy).

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)  
public @interface CustomAnnotation{
     public boolean enabled() default true;
 }
```

`CustomAnnotation.class.getClass()` gives me `interface mypackage.CustomAnnotation`

`methodInvocation.getMethod().getAnnotations()[0].getClass()` gives me `@mypackage.CustomAnnotation`

So equals returns false between two getClass() methods of the same annotation.

I have `List<Class> annotationClassList`, I added to the list `CustomAnnotation.getClass()`;

I want to check if `methodInvocation.getMethod().getAnnotations()[0].getClass()` is on the list.

What is the best way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

CustomAnnotation.class.equals(methodInvocation.getMethod().getAnnotations()[0]) should do the trick. 
CustomAnnotation.class.getClass() should retun java.lang.Class